# Frequency of EMR vs clockspeed of a processor

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, frequency, computer

I was recently reading [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/hardware/comments/58f7p7/whenll_we_finally_see_a_terahertz_processor/) on Reddit where people discussed the implications of a "Terahertz processor", a computer processor that operates at a clockspeed of greater than 1 Terahertz (THz). My question is about [this comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/hardware/comments/58f7p7/comment/d8zyqq5/), which suggests that a processor operating at a clock speed of 400-800 THz would "start producing visible light." (All the sub-commenters seem to agree.)

Am I correct in assessing that this is complete nonsense? While clock speed and frequency of electromagnetic radiation happen to share the same unit (they measure the number of times something happens in a second), aren't they completely different quantities? Is a processor operating at a clock speed of X Hz really emitting electromagnetic radiation at a frequency of X Hz?

This question is a bit non-standard for this forum, so I apologize in advance and will delete it if it is shown to break Community guidelines.

Comment: *Is a processor operating at a clock speed of X Hz really emitting electromagnetic radiation at a frequency of X Hz?* I don’t see why it wouldn’t. Don’t there have to be electrons in the circuitry oscillating at X Hz? Don’t today’s processors produce lower-frequency EM waves?